# How can i make object accessible without needing self variable?

Tags: python, oop, object, discord.py

For example in discord.py:

```
import discord
discord.Status.dnd
```

^ Another example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, word):
        print(word)
```

It would require A = Test("blah") for this work, But how do i make it like Test("blah") instead of giving it variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```py
class Test:
    word = ''

print(Test.word) #Will return ''
Test.word = 'Blah'
print(Test.word) #Will return 'Blah'

instance = Test()

print(instance.word) #Will return 'Blah'
instance.word = 'Wow'
print(instance.word) #Will return 'Wow'

print(Test.word) #Will still return 'Blah'
```

Comment: If this was the solutuon to your problem, consider accepting it, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)